# The UIButton in collection view header is not working when invoked from collection view controller, how to fix this?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionViewCell file that consist of a button. When I click this button, I want to change the button label from "follow" to "unfollow" (like instagram) and I am calling this on click button function in my UICollectionView Controller swift file using protocols and delegates. But the button just doesn't seem to respond.

I have added the UICollectionViewCell as a supplementaryViewofKind as well in the controller and yet, there is a problem. Also made sure I conformed to the delegate protocals

```
// ********* VIEW FILE (UserProfileHeader.swift) *********
class UserProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell {

var delegate: UserProfileHeaderDelegate?

let editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
 let button = UIButton(type: .system)
 button.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
 button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditProfileFollow), 
 for: .touchUpInside)
 return button
    }()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame: frame)

  addSubview(editProfileFollowButton)

    }

@objc func handleEditProfileFollow(){
        delegate?.handleEditFollowTapped(for: self)
    }

}

// ********* CONTROLLER FILE (UserProfileVC.swift) *********
class UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewController, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UserProfileHeaderDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //register collection views
    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, 
    forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.collectionView.register(UserProfileHeader.self, 
    forSupplementaryViewOfKind: 
    UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: 
    headerIdentifier)

}


override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) 
-> Int {
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}

// declaring the header collection view
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = 
      collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, 
      withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! 
      UserProfileHeader
    header.delegate = self
    return header
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 220)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = 
      collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
      reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    return cell
}


func handleEditFollowTapped(for header: UserProfileHeader){
    if header.editProfileFollowButton.titleLabel?.text == "Follow"{
        header.editProfileFollowButton.setTitle("Following", for: 
          .normal)
    } else {
        header.editProfileFollowButton.setTitle("Follow", for: 
          .normal)
    }
}

}

// ********* PROTOCOL FILE (protocols.swift) *********
protocol UserProfileHeaderDelegate {
 func handleEditFollowTapped(for header: UserProfileHeader)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem im seeing is that you cannot add a target in an `anonymous closure`, the reason is that self doesn't exist at the time the button is created.

And easy fix for this can be deleting the line following line in the buttons creation:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditProfileFollow), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And in `init` just add the following line after `super.init`:

```
editProfileFollowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditProfileFollow), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's fixed. You're a life saver :D ... Simple mistakes sometimes cause so much delay.